# svnsync cannot recover from source idle disconnect

Tags: svn, reverse-proxy, svnsync

If I try to mirror a 3rd-party repo to a local one then while `svnsync` is uploading a 300M+ file to the slow destination server the source server disconnects and `svnsync` does not try to reconnect to it and enters infinite loop. How to workaround this?

```
C:\progs\svnsync-dir>svnsync --version
svnsync, version 1.14.0 (r1876290)
   compiled May 24 2020, 17:07:49 on x86-microsoft-windows

C:\progs\svnsync-dir>svnsync --steal-lock sync https://targetreposito.acme.com/s
vn/Reponame
Stole lock previously held by 'my-host-name:ab204a7a-756f-2947-af9c-caf904a8945d
'
Transmitting file data .........................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
............< here it hangs
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After compiling the svn communication library `serf` from trunk `svnsync` instead of hanging is now crashing with `An error occurred during decompression` or (if

```
[global]
http-compression = no
```

) in `~/.subversion/servers` then with `Malformed XML: no element found`.

After dumping the HTTP conversation between svnsync and the source server I figured out that the source server closed connection while svnsync was flushing partially received delta to the destination server.

The solution is to use the `pv` tool with `slice` disabled and a huge buffer to hold the full response: `pv -q -C -B4G`

<strike>Add to /etc/hosts:</strike>

```
127.0.0.3 svn.acme.com
1.2.3.4   svn.acme.com.real
```

Then run:

```
sudo socat TCP-LISTEN:443,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:"./hugebuf.sh svn.acme.com.real 443",nofork
```

Run:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:3128,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:"./hugebuf.sh -p",nofork
```

[hugebuf.sh](https://gist.github.com/basinilya/ac9cdadfe53807d562e02e1ee4de96f9) (simplified):

```
#!/bin/bash
host=${1:?}
port=${2:?}
exec 4>"/dev/tcp/${host:?}/${port}"
cat <&0 >&4 &
pv -q -C -B4G <&4
```

Lastly, run the svnsync command with extra args:

```
svnsync --config-option servers:global:http-proxy-host=localhost --config-option servers:global:http-proxy-port=3128
```

Now it's able to commit this very revision.

The above works with msys / git-for-windows too.

- https://packages.msys2.org/package/pv?repo=msys&variant=x86_64
- https://packages.msys2.org/package/socat?repo=msys&variant=x86_64